# using Hashlib with Kivy/Buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have created an app with Kivy, it has `hashlib` as one of the libraries. When trying to build it with buildozer, I get the following error:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you successfully build without hashlib?

Comment: yeah i can, ive found a workaround where i use 'import md5' and remove the hashlib. but its annoying that i cant use hashlib.

Comment: I am also having issue with the same as when created a app with Kivy, it has hashlib as one of the library's when trying to build with buildozer ,the app crashes and it successfully build without hashlib , as I am using  RIPEMD-160 hash algorithm.